# Active link color not coming in Woocommerce category right sidebar widget

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this link: http://www.aaq.co.il/shop/?product_cat=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A2&dppage=1

ON this page there is a right sidebar of product category of Woocommerce plugin. I want to change the link color to blue so that it shows which page is currently active. I have tried all the possible CSS code but didn't worked.

When you right click and do inspect element and force the element to be active the changes shows but it doesn't appear directly on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(function(){
   jQuery("a").each(function(){
           if (jQuery(this).attr("href") == window.location.href){
                   jQuery(this).addClass("active");
           }
       });
    });
});
```

This will add an "active" class to the links. You can then add CSS to style as needed.